# How to return the two numbers passed into the callback function

Tags: javascript

Two functions:

- First multiplies two numbers
- Second takes three parameters a callback function and two numbers.

It should return the two numbers passed into the callback function.

```
function multiply(param1,param2){
      return param1*param2;
}
function calculator(callback,param3,param4) {
   let param1 =param3; 
   let param2=param4;
   //return callback(param1,param2);
   return[param1,param2];
}
```

I need to have in return two  numbers parameters passed into multiply function
not multiplied !!

Comment: Why pass callback if you only return what you pass as args ?

Comment: The code you wrote does just what you ask : it returns the two numbers in an array.

What else do you want?

Answer (score 4):

You could just return the result of calling `callback` with the given parameters.

```js
function multiply(param1, param2) {
    return param1 * param2;
}

function calculator(callback, param1, param2) {
    return callback(param1, param2);
}

console.log(calculator(multiply, 6, 7));
```